# Convert a list within a list to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's assume I have the following list: `my_lst = [['a', ['b']], ['a1', ['b1']]]`. I want to convert it to `"a b, a1 b1"`.

```
my_lst = [['a', ['b']], ['a1', ['b1']]]
for i in my_lst:
    first_idx = i[0]
    second_idx = i[1][0]
    print(f"{first_idx} {second_idx}", end=",")
```

My code gives `a b,a1 b1,`. I don't understand how to remove the comma from the end.

Comment: all of the second elements are single in the list ? like `b` and `b1`?

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar there may be several elements, for example [['a', ['b']], ['a1', ['b1', 'b2']]]

Comment: `i[1][0]` will only get `b1`, not `b2`. Is that OK?

Comment: If you want all of them, use `{' '.join(i[1])}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't print each string in the loop, use `join()` to combine them with comma separators.

```
result = ','.join(f"{i[0]} {' '.join(i[1])}" for i in my_lst)
print(result)
```

If you want to distribute the elements of `i[1]`, you can use nested joins:

```
my_lst = [['a', ['b']], ['a1', ['b1', 'b2']]]

result = ','.join(','.join(f"{i[0]} {j}" for j in i[1]) for i in my_lst)
print(result) # a b,a1 b1,a1 b2
```

Comment: Thank you. I have question, what if I wanted to return ['a1', ['b1', 'b2']] as a1 b1, a1 b2 and not as a1 b1 b2. What could be done in this case?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: very clever, I didn't think of using the format and thought why use the join three times) I think the easiest thing for me here would be to create a separate list with all the unique cars, and then use the join.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
my_lst = [['a', ['b']], ['a1', ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']]]
```

This

```
[ [h, *t] for h, t in my_lst ]
```

gives you

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']]
```

this

```
[ ' '.join([h, *t]) for h, t in my_lst ]
```

returns

```
['a b', 'a1 b1 b2 b3']
```

and finally this

```
', '.join( ' '.join([h, *t]) for h, t in my_lst )
```

returns

```
'a b, a1 b1 b2 b3'
```

which appears to be what you're looking for